# booking flights to iceland when wanting to arrive and leave from different cities

Tags: air-travel, car-rentals, iceland

I will be going to Iceland for a couple of weeks in Feb.  Is it possible to fly into Akureryi and rent a car and then fly out of Keflavik?  Is it alot more expensive to do it this way?  Do I need to book two one way flights or can it be done as a round trip?
Thanks,

Comment: Please ask one question and do some research beforehand. No one will look for you whether it’s more expensive or not or whether a airline allows such a round trip.

Answer (score 1):

For the flights, as I understand it as long as the overland leg is shorter than the flown legs and the flown legs are on compatible airlines it's normally possible for the two legs of such a trip to be booked on the same ticket with each leg being priced at "half return" pricing.

Google flights offers a "multi-city" option that can be used to look for such flights.

The awkward bit in this case is it looks like Akureyri Airport has few international flights, and the domestic flights from Akureyri to Reykjavík mostly go to a different airport to the international ones, so unless you are very lucky it looks like you will have a connection with change of airport in Reykjavík.

For the car I would expect a surcharge for a one way rental, though I've no idea how much it would be in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options getting from Akureyri to Reykjavík.

## Domestic plane

You can [fly](https://www.airicelandconnect.com/) directly to the Keflavík Airport, or to the Reykjavík domestic airport depending on the time of the day. Time is **45 minutes**.

## Busses

There are busses for you to take. They make stops at gas station/restaurants every now and then. It will take about **6 hours**, the same as with a car.

## Rented Car

Not the cheapest option. About 6 hours and the are many gas stations, supermarkets and restaurants on the way. Very nice trip.

## Share a car

Car sharing is common in Iceland but it requires you to be very flexible.